# Excel 2016 fails on VBA PasteSpecial

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

This VBA code is running on Excel 2013 (on multiple different machines):

```
Sub CopyStaticData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Data Input").Range("Input_Station_ID").Copy
    Sheets("Data Received").Range("Data_Station_ID").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ...
```

However, on Excel 2016 it throws a runtime error on the last line:

> Error 1004: Method 'PasteSpecial' of object 'Range' failed

I tried replacing xlPasteValues with its explicit code (-4163) - to no avail.

Any ideas? A possible Microsoft compatibility issue?

Comment: Should it not be.. `PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: @Davesexcel It can be, but `Paste:=xlPasteValues` is equally valid.

Comment: Ah, yes..I usually don't use it.

Comment: What kind of ranges are they? Are the ranges the same size. Usually you would just paste the copy range into the first cell of the paste range. Not the entire range.

Comment: Thanks Davesexcel. Same erro with this command format as well. Seems like a compatibility issue between Excel versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for pasting values only, i recommend not using a copy.

instead, simplify to `RangeB.value = RangeA.value`.

easier, faster, no tricky clipboard, written in one small line.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick. I'll take your advice a a workaround (some ranges copied are pretty large, implement with loops and direct assignment).